# create a Dynamic CountIf String for cell equation VBA

Tags: string, excel, vba, count, countif

I have a table where new data is continuously inserted. If the category exists in Column B, data is inputted in a new row under that category from B#:F#. But if it doesn't exist a new row is created for that category title and then data is inserted underneath.
Column A includes a Count for each category and is placed in cell left to the first instance a category appears. For example if column b had 6 "orange" occurrences, then a count is to the left of (col A) the first instance of orange.

How can I ensure that if a new category (lets say "hello") which is set to the variable tgt is added in a new row, that the countif statement in the code dynamically changes to the value that is set to tgt?

```
Dim tgtVal As String
         tgtVal = tgt.Value
         tgt.Offset(0, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[1], " & tgtVal & ")-1"
```

Now a count does pop up in the sheet next to the newly inserted category however it is not the correct count. The equation is

> "=COUNTIF(B:B, Hello)-1" with a count of -1
>   in the cell instead of
>   =COUNTIF(B:B, "Hello")-1 with a count of 1

If I add another pair of quotes in the code to attempt to include quotes in the countif statement in the sheet like:

> tgt.Offset(0, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[1], "" & tgtVal & "")-1"
>   then it shows up as
>   =COUNTIF(B:B, " & tgtVal & ")-1 as the equation in the cell

How do I make sure it comes up as "**tgtVal**" and not **tgtVal** in the cell's equation?

Comment: Can you share youe Sheet ? and the desired result sheet ?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to build a string literal, you should output the result to the immediate window.  This will help you detect if the any errors.

This is the result of your code snippet `"=COUNTIF(C[1], "" & tgtVal & "")-1"`.  Notice that `& tgtVal &` is actually part of the string.

> =COUNTIF(C[1], " & tgtVal & ")-1

Here are two ways to get the correct result `=COUNTIF(C[1],"")-1`

String literal

> "=COUNTIF(C[1],""" & tgtVal & """)-1"

Using the ASCII code for a double quote

> "=COUNTIF(C[1]," & Chr(34) & tgtVal & Chr(34) & """)-1"